# What is the correct configuration for multiple domains to be hosted under the same webspace in Plesk?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, multiple-domains, plesk

I have multiple domains, which I hope to add to Plesk using an API, to be hosted under the same webspace. As in `firstsite.example` will the main, but the `secondsite.example` and `thirdsite.example` will share the same diskspace, but have different emails.

I have read through some of the API documents, but could not figure out what is the best way to approach doing so. Is it possible? Is it recommended?

Comment: What do you mean by "share the same diskspace"?   Do you want the same document root for all of them so that they serve the same content?   Do you want each of them to be a subdirectory from some users directory?

Comment: Same document root, but with the option to change that later on.

Comment: Plesk is probably not flexible enough for you.  It has [domain aiiases](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-to-create-domain-aliases-plesk) that share document root, but I don't think they have separate email configuration.  Why are you configuring this via Plesk?  It sounds like getting a virtual private server (VPS) and configuring everything yourself outside of  Plesk would give you the flexibility you need.

Comment: That's what i thoughtnat first, but then i figured i could use the API to automated a bunch of the work.